# Thread-safe queue implementation in C

Tags: multithreading, queue, thread-safety

I have a single queue on which thread1 is pushing (enqueuing) data and thread2 is pulling (dequeuing) data. How can I make it thread-safe right from the queue creation?

I also want to know a best way to convey thread1 about creation of the queue (which is done in thread1), so that thread2 can start pushing data to the queue.

Comment: What did you try so far? What environment do yo work in?

Comment: I am working on Linux (gcc). I thought of using mutex lock while enqueuing and dequeuing. But currently I tried without any mutex and conditional variables. It is working fine. But I'm not sure it will work in all cases or not.